# What is this beast? A riddle

Tags: riddle, word

A snake-sounding head

A snake-looking tail

I fly with just 2 flaps

And I lay just eggs

What am I?

Comment: FYI you cannot tag people who have not commented on your post yet. According to the tag description the answer may be "a word or a set of words but not a phrase or sentence"

Comment: @IchthysKing Leaving it up to you but I'd strongly consider adding the information that the answer is more than one word to the puzzle itself.